# How to load templates in subdirectories

Tags: go, go-templates

I currently have all my html files in a flat directory `templates/` and I load everything in with

```
tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
```

But I'd like to now bring in some structure and put templates into folders, `components`, `base`, etc. But when I do my site stops working. I'm thinking it could be the above, or could it also be that I need to reference the path in the template?

example

```
{{ template "navbar" }}
```

would become

```
{{ template "components/navbar" }}
```

Slightly confused...

I'm also using the native go library not a framework, for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go's glob does not support matching files in sub-directories, i.e. `**` is not supported.

You can either use a third party lib (there are a number of implementations on github), or you could invoke `filepath.Glob` for each "level" of sub-directories and aggregate the returned file names into a single slice and then pass the slice to `template.ParseFiles`:

```
dirs := []string{
    "templates/*.html",
    "templates/*/*.html",
    "templates/*/*/*.html",
    // ...
}

files := []string{}
for _, dir := range dirs {
    ff, err := filepath.Glob(dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    files = append(files, ff...)
}

t, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// ...
```

---

You also need to keep in mind how [`ParseFiles`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) works: *(emphasis mine)*

> ParseFiles creates a new Template and parses the template definitions
>   from the named files. The returned template's name will have the
>   (base) name and (parsed) contents of the first file. There must be at
>   least one file. If an error occurs, parsing stops and the returned
>   *Template is nil.
>
> **When parsing multiple files with the same name in different
>   directories, the last one mentioned will be the one that results.** For
>   instance, ParseFiles("a/foo", "b/foo") stores "b/foo" as the template
>   named "foo", while "a/foo" is unavailable.

This means that, if you want to load all the files, you have to ensure at least one of two things: (1) that each file's *base* name is unique across all template files, not just in the directory in which the file's located, or (2) provide a unique template name for each file by using the `{{ define "<template_name>" }}` action at the top of the file's contents (and do not forget the `{{ end }}` to close the `define` action).

---

As an example for the 2nd approach, let's say, in your templates you have two files that have the same base name, e.g. `templates/foo/header.html` and `templates/bar/header.html` and their contents are as follows:

`templates/foo/header.html`

```
<head><title>Foo Site</title></head>
```

`templates/bar/header.html`

```
<head><title>Bar Site</title></head>
```

Now to give the these files a unique template name you can change the contents to this:

`templates/foo/header.html`

```
{{ define "foo/header" }}
<head><title>Foo Site</title></head>
{{ end }}
```

`templates/bar/header.html`

```
{{ define "bar/header" }}
<head><title>Bar Site</title></head>
{{ end }}
```

After you do this, you can either execute them directly with `t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "foo/header", nil)`, or indirectly by having other templates reference them using the `{{ template "bar/header" . }}` action.

Comment: Getting an error at `files = append(files, ff)`, `cannot use ff as type string`, otherwise this makes sense, thanks! added changed to `files = append(files, ff...)` works!

Comment: @Ari my bad, fixed now.